# Getting error while using max and over by with sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to get a maximum value of date and I am using the oracle database. It was working quite well but suddenly it's not working.

```
select max(scn_dtm) over (partition by name, id )-current_date from iv_p_co_iaw_subjects_v1

scn_dtm        name     id
2020-01-30     BEL-17   14
2012-01-25     BEL-84   030102
2007-01-30     ABC-54   RU10012
2012-01-03     RED-23   D52
```

Update on error:

```
SQL Error [50006] [HY000]: Error executing view: Function max is not executable
```

Apologies on this, I am indeed using denodo to create views from querying Oracle database.

Comment: Order by is mandatory in Over clause while partition by is optional.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov: that's wrong. `order by` is optional. And for `max()` adding an `order by` actually changes the meaning of the function.

Comment: @mohdatif: neither `order by` nor `partition by` is mandatory.

Comment: @KSp: what is the error you get

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought about running window

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Show us desired output please

Comment: @KSp . . . The error is not an Oracle error so that tag looks suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

This error is not an Oracle error:

> SQL Error [50006] [HY000]: Error executing view: Function max is not executable

Googling the error brings up pages about a tool called Denodo -- and Denodo does not appear to support window functions. I am suspicious that the underlying database is Oracle at all and wonder if you might be using an older version of MySQL that does not support window functions.

Answer (score 0):

Query you wrote *works*, at least on my 11g, although comments regarding the missing `order by` clause under your question suggest differently:

```
SQL> with iv_p_co_iaw_subjects_v1 (scn_dtm, name, id) as
  2    (select date '2020-01-30', 'bel-17', '14'      from dual union all
  3     select date '2012-01-25', 'bel-84', '030102'  from dual union all
  4     select date '2007-01-30', 'abc-54', 'ru10012' from dual union all
  5     select date '2012-01-03', 'red-23', 'd52'     from dual
  6  )
  7  select max(scn_dtm) over (partition by name, id ) - current_date
  8  from iv_p_co_iaw_subjects_v1;

MAX(SCN_DTM)OVER(PARTITIONBYNAME,ID)-CURRENT_DATE
-------------------------------------------------
                                       -4943,4971
                                       -195,49707
                                       -3122,4971
                                       -3144,4971

SQL>
```

You said that there's an error - why do you expect us to *guess* which one? And, what happened since "suddenly"? Maybe that caused the error.

Comment: SQL Error [50006] [HY000]: Error executing view: Function max is not executable

Comment: well, my data is a view that's why it says error executing view

Comment: This: "**SQL Error [50006] [HY000]**" doesn't look like Oracle. Oracle errors look like e.g. ORA-00942 or PLS-00201, not like what you posted.

Comment: I see. I know nothing about Denodo, sorry.